# Memoize decorators failing to memoize (when not using decorator syntax)

Tags: python, decorator

I've got a simple memoizer decorator:

```py
def funcmemo(f):
    memo = {}
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
    if args in memo:
        return memo[args]
    else:
        temp = f(*args)
        print "memoizing: ", args, temp  
        memo[args] = temp
        return temp
    return wrapper
```

Now, when I use it via the "@" token,

```py
@funcmemo
def fib(n):
    print "fib called with:", n
    if n < 2: return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

res = fib(3)
print "result:", res
```

it works correctly, as seen in the printed output:

```py
fib called with: 3
fib called with: 1
memoizing:  (1,) 1
fib called with: 2
fib called with: 0
memoizing:  (0,) 0
memoizing:  (2,) 1
memoizing:  (3,) 2
result:  2
```

However, when I do this:

```py
def fib(n):
    print "fib called with:", n
    if n < 2: return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

memfib = funcmemo(fib)
res = memfib(3)
print "result:", res
```

Apparently an undecorated fib gets called, with only the final return value "reaching" the cache (obviously resulting in huge slowdown):

```py
fib called with: 3
fib called with: 1
fib called with: 2
fib called with: 0
fib called with: 1
memoizing:  (3,) 2
result: 2
```

Curiously, this one works fine:

```py
def fib(n):
    print "fib called with:", n
    if n < 2: return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

fib = funcmemo(fib)
res = fib(3)
print "result:", res
```

Also, the very same thing happens with a class-based version:

```py
class Classmemo(object):
    def __init__ (self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.mem = {}
    def __call__ (self, *args):
        if args in self.mem:
            return self.mem[args]
        else:
            tmp = self.f(*args)
            print "memoizing: ", args, temp
            self.mem[args] = tmp
            return tmp
```

The problem also occurs when using an "anonymous" decorated function, like

```py
res = Classmemo(fib)(3)
```

I'd be glad to be enlightened about the reasons behind this.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  But where is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing curious about this. When you do

```
memofib = funcmemo(fib)
```

You're not changing the function `fib` points to in any way, but creating a *new function* and pointing the name `memofib` at it.

So when `memofib` gets called, it calls the function pointed to by the name `fib` -- which recursively calls itself, not `memofib` -- so no memoization occurs.

In your second example, you do

```
fib = funcmemo(fib)
```

so it calls itself recursively and memoization happens at all levels.

If you don't want to overwrite the name `fib`, as the decorator version or your second example does, you could alter `fib` to take a function name:

```
def fib(n, fibfunc):
    print "fib called with:", n
    if n < 2: return n
    return fibfunc(n-2, fibfunc) + fibfunc(n-1, fibfunc)

memofib = funcmemo(fib)
res = fib(3, memofib)
```

You could also use a [fixed point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) to avoid passing `fibfunc` every time:

```
def Y(f):
    def Yf(*args):
        return f(Yf)(*args)
    return f(Yf)

@Y
def fib(f):
    def inner_fib(n):
        print "fib called with:", n
        if n < 2: return n
        return f(n-2) + f(n-1)
    return inner_fib
```

Comment: Also, thanks for setting me on a course to complete brain meltdown by bringing up fixed point combinators.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I couldn't resist :). As soon as I typed in the the version that passes the function around, I realized this was probably _the only time_ I'd ever get to use one where it wasn't specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In case your question is just a simple *why*, I guess the answer is just because the recursion-call with `fib()` does call the function with the name `fib()`.  To decorate that you have to replace the value of the pointer `fib`; this is not done by `memfib = funcmemo(fib)` nor by the class version.