# How can I refer to a function not by name in its definition in python?

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming

I am maintaining a little library of useful functions for interacting with my company's APIs and I have come across (what I think is) a neat question that I can't find the answer to.

I frequently have to request large amounts of data from an API, so I do something like:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def get_data(self, offset = 0):
        done = False
        while not done:
            data = get_more_starting_at(offset)
            self.data.extend(data)
            offset += 1
            if not data:
                done = True
```

This works fine and allows me to restart the retrieval where I left off if something goes  horribly wrong. However, since python functions are just regular objects, we can do stuff like:

```
def yo():
    yo.hi = "yo!"
    return None
```

and then we can interrogate yo about its properties later, like:

```
yo.hi => "yo!"
```

my question is: Can I rewrite my class-based example to pin the data to the function itself, without referring to the function by name. I know I can do this by:

```
def get_data(offset=0):
    done = False
    get_data.data = []
    while not done:
        data = get_more_starting_from(offset)
        get_data.data.extend(data)
        offset += 1
        if not data:
            done = True
    return get_data.data
```

but I would like to do something like:

```
def get_data(offset=0):
    done = False
    self.data = [] # <===== this is the bit I can't figure out
    while not done:
        data = get_more_starting_from(offset)
        self.data.extend(data) # <====== also this!
        offset += 1
        if not data:
            done = True
    return self.data # <======== want to refer to the "current" object
```

Is it possible to refer to the "current" object by anything other than its name?
Something like "this", "self", or "memememe!" is what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you do this, you have one such binding per function object - in many cases (except if you use higher-order functions), that means once per interpreter process. So barring certain circumstances, you're asking for global state. And in your example, you don't even need anything like that, you can simply use a local variable.

Comment: @agf, they are not meant to be instance methods. I am wondering about using functions (not methods) as an object to hold data for use across multiple calls to the function.

Comment: @Andbdrew So your question is "How can I refer to a function __not by name__ within itself?" or is it "How can a function store __multiple different sets of data for multiple passes__?"

Comment: @agf It is "How can I refer to a function not by name within itself?" Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: What I'm asking is I don't see what it is your third code snippet is trying to do different from what your second does. __Why not__ just refer to it by name?

Comment: @agf in the third snippet, I am trying to attach the data to "self.data" as if "self" referred to the function itself, which it does not do. "self" may have been a bad choice of name.

Comment: @agf it is of course perfectly reasonable to refer to it by name, but I am just wondering if it is possible to refer to it more generally. This is not really a practical issue right now. The class-based example works well and is much nicer to read and look at :)

Comment: @delnan you are right about being able to use a local variable for this, but I am wondering if it is possible to make it work as I described.

Comment: The question does not make much sense, as a function exists exactly once. You can always refer to it by name. That `self` would simply be a macro to insert the function name, a task more suitable for a text editor. The point of a classes 'self' is that there can be multiple instances and you have to be able to refer to the current one.

Comment: @JochenRitzel See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819651/memoize-decorators-failing-to-memoize-when-not-using-decorator-syntax for an example of why you might want to refer to a function inside itself not by name. While this isn't a good example, there are situations where you might want to.

Comment: More broadly, in Python the name you use to define a function can be reassigned willy-nilly to some other object at any time. Usually this doesn't happen, and when it does happen it usually doesn't matter since most functions don't refer to themselves, but it's nice to have a way to get a nigh-immutable reference to a function when you're doing recursion or assigning attributes on it.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you wanted to replace your class with just a function, then you could just use a global variable (name something like `_get_data_state`), since that's what an attribute on a global function object effectively is anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand **why** you want to do this, but it's what a [fixed point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) allows you to do:

```
import functools

def Y(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def Yf(*args):
        return inner(*args)
    inner = f(Yf)
    return Yf

@Y
def get_data(f):
    def inner_get_data(*args):
        # This is your real get data function
        # define it as normal
        # but just refer to it as 'f' inside itself
        print 'setting get_data.foo to', args
        f.foo = args
    return inner_get_data

get_data(1, 2, 3)

print get_data.foo
```

So you call `get_data` as normal, and it "magically" knows that `f` means itself.

Comment: awesome. For now, I just want to do this for fun, but I may have some more mundane (read useful) purpose at another time! thanks!

Comment: Nice. I have in the past recommended a decorator for this (having the reference to the function passed in as the first argument, a la `self`) but this is slicker in some ways.

Comment: @kindall I really never thought there could be any reason to use a fixed point combinator in Python, but this is the second question in a week where I got to use it (see my last comment on the question).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, but (a) the data is not per-function-invocation, but per function (b) it's much easier to achieve this sort of thing with a class.

If you had to do it, you might do something like this:

```
def ybother(a,b,c,yrselflambda = lambda: ybother):
    yrself = yrselflambda()
    #other stuff
```

The lambda is necessary, because you need to delay evaluation of the term `ybother` until something has been bound to it.

Alternatively, and increasingly pointlessly:

```
from functools import partial
def ybother(a,b,c,yrself=None):
    #whatever
    yrself.data = [] # this will blow up if the default argument is used
    #more stuff

bothered = partial(ybother, yrself=ybother)
```

Or:

```
def unbothered(a,b,c):
    def inbothered(yrself):
        #whatever
        yrself.data = []

    return inbothered, inbothered(inbothered)
```

This last version gives you a different function object each time, which you might like.

There are almost certainly introspective tricks to do this, but they are even less worthwhile.

Comment: You're still referring to the function by name. I don't see what this gains him? You can already use the function name inside its body because the body isn't executed until after the function is defined.

Comment: @agf I'm not sure what any of this gets him. This answer avoids having to have the name of the function inside the function, which I understand is what OP wanted.

Comment: @Marcin your answers are cool also! Thank you for your time responding! It seems like functools is totally sweet.

Comment: Great update. The last one is essentially what you get out of the fixed point combinator if you apply the transform in the inner function (return `f(Yf)(*args)` inside Yf) instead of outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what doing it like this gains you, but what about using a decorator.

```
import functools

def add_self(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        if not getattr(f, 'content', None):
            f.content = []
        return f(f, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@add_self
def example(self, arg1):
    self.content.append(arg1)
    print self.content


example(1)
example(2)
example(3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```